# Half of the lights reversed on one switch

Tags: light

I have 4 lights in one room running off of one switch.  This has worked great until now.  All of a sudden, two of the lights turn on dimly while the other two are off when the switch is in the off position.  When you turn the switch on, the dim lights turn off and the other two lights turn on as they should.

Comment: Be absolutely sure they are not on a 3way switch and take pictures of the switch and wiring to it and in the switch box and post them here.

Comment: All of a sudden sounds more like mice or you forgot to mention the nail/screw you put into the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Disregard this question because after further troubleshooting, I found that for some reason the lights that turn on when the switch is off, somehow has another breaker feeding it power.  Bottom line is I have to trace out that breaker and disconnect that power feed.

Comment: Two breakers to one light circuit? Scary. Maybe a shared neutral.